# Path dependence of $\lim\limits_{(n,m)\to(\infty, \infty)}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}\right)^m$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =e$$

and the geometric series :$$\lim_{n\to∞}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$$ will converge to 1

so  what will happen if i do this
$$\lim\limits_{(n, m)\to (\infty, \infty)}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}\right)^m$$
will the answer will be $1$ or $e$ or will depend on the path of $n$, $m$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: rewrite the function as $(1-2^{-n})^m$, then consider paths of the form $m=k2^n$ to prove there's no limit.

Comment: Please avoid subject lines that consist only of mathematical formulas/mathjax, as they interfere with some navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k} = 1 - 2^{-n}$$

So

\begin{align}
\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\right)^m &= \left(1 - 2^{-n}\right)^m\\
&= \exp\left(m \ln \left(1 - 2^{-n}\right)\right)\\
&= \exp\left(m2^{-n}\right)\exp\left(1 + \mathcal O\left(2^{-n}\right)\right)
\end{align}

Let $x\in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, and $m = \left\lfloor x 2^{n}\right\rfloor$, then $m2^{-n} \to x$ as $n\to\infty$ and so:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty,\; m = \left\lfloor x 2^{n}\right\rfloor}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}\right)^m = e^x$$

Answer (score 1):

More in general $\left(a_n\right)^{b_n}$ with $a_n \to 1$ and $b_n \to\infty$ is an indeterminate form, that is path dependent, indeed

$$\left(a_n\right)^{b_n} =e^{b_n \log a_n}$$

then all boils down in the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n \log a_n$$

which can be any real number, let consider for example

- $a_n=1\pm \frac1n$ and $b_n=n^2 \implies b_n \log a_n \to \pm \infty$
- $a_n=1 \pm \frac a n$ and $b_n=n \implies b_n \log a_n \to \pm a$
- $a_n=1\pm \frac1n$ and $b_n=\sqrt n \implies b_n \log a_n \to 0$